# Split Python list of strings into seperate lists based on character

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I'm trying to figure out how to split the following list into separate lists based on a character in the list.

```
list = ['@', '2014', '00:03:01', 'Matt', '"login"', '0.01', '@', '2014', '02:06:12', 'Mary', '"login"', '0.01']
```

I want to create a list after every "@" symbol is introduced. For example, I would want the output to be the following:

```
NewList1 = ['@', '2014', '00:03:01', 'Matt', '"login"', '0.01'] 

NewList2 = ['@', '2014', '02:06:12', 'Mary', '"login"', '0.01']
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Don't name you `list` `list`, you are override the build in `list()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
>>> lst=['@', '2014', '00:03:01', 'Matt', '"login"', '0.01', '@', '2014', '02:06:12', 'Mary', '"login"', '0.01']
>>> [item.split() for item in ' '.join(lst).split('@') if item]
[['2014', '00:03:01', 'Matt', '"login"', '0.01'], 
 ['2014', '02:06:12', 'Mary', '"login"', '0.01']]
```

So what this basically does is join the list together, re-split it on `@` and then converts each group back to a list.

Comment: Thank you! Is it at all possible to keep the string of '@' in the new lists created?

Comment: You could just do `['@']+item.split()` instead of just `item.split()` in the list comprehension.

Comment: Once you got a `@` in any of those elements you are suddenly in trouble.

Comment: if any of the items in `lst` have whitespace inside then it produces wrong result.

Comment: From the users input examples, I think it is OK to assume that there are no other occurences of `@` or whitespace in the elements.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools as IT
import operator

seq = ['@', '2014', '00:03:01', 'Matt', '"login"', '0.01', '@', '2014', '02:06:12', 'Mary', '"login"', '0.01']

groups = (list(g) for k,g in IT.groupby(seq, lambda item: item=='@'))
print(list(IT.starmap(operator.add, IT.izip(*[groups]*2))))
```

prints

```
[['@', '2014', '00:03:01', 'Matt', '"login"', '0.01'], ['@', '2014', '02:06:12', 'Mary', '"login"', '0.01']]
```

Comment: Not sure the `starmap` is necessary given it's a constant grouping var:  `groups = [['@'] + list(g) for ... if not k` is possibly more straight-forward...

Answer (score 1):

Repeatedly find the index of the element with `'@'` in the list, starting from the previous position of `'@'` and take whatever is there in the middle in the result.

```
idx, result = 0, []
while True:
    try:
        temp = my_list.index('@', idx + 1)
        result.append(my_list[idx + 1:temp])
        idx = temp
    except ValueError, e:
        result.append(my_list[idx + 1:])
        break
print result
# [['2014', '00:03:01', 'Matt', '"login"', '0.01'],
#  ['2014', '02:06:12', 'Mary', '"login"', '0.01']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect use for [`more_itertools.split_before`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_before). The resulting one-liner is both concise and clear.

```
from more_itertools import split_before

original = ['@', '2014', '00:03:01', 'Matt', '"login"', '0.01',
            '@', '2014', '02:06:12', 'Mary', '"login"', '0.01']

processed = [sublist for sublist in split_before(original, lambda i: i == '@')]

print(processed)
```

Output (line break added for clarity):

```
[['@', '2014', '00:03:01', 'Matt', '"login"', '0.01'],
 ['@', '2014', '02:06:12', 'Mary', '"login"', '0.01']]
```