# Python split a list into several lists for each new line character

Tags: python

I have the following list, and I would like to split it into several lists when the element in the list is "\n".

Input:

```
['chain 2109 chrY 59373566 + 1266734 1266761 chrX 156040895 + 1198245 1198272 20769290\n', '27\n','\n','chain 2032 chrY 59373566 + 1136192 1136219 chrX 156040895 + 1086629 1086656 4047064\n','27\n','\n']
```

expected output:

```
[
 ['chain 2109 chrY 59373566 + 1266734 1266761 chrX 156040895 + 1198245 1198272 20769290', '27'],
 ['chain 2032 chrY 59373566 + 1136192 1136219 chrX 156040895 + 1086629 1086656 4047064', '27']
]
```

I tried stripping the elements with "\n" at the end of them and used and modified the accepted answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747796/13628404):

```
for i, n in enumerate(lst):
    if n != "\n":
        lst[i] = lst[i].rstrip("\n")

[item.split(",") for item in ','.join(lst).split('\n') if item]
```

But since I am using a comma instead of a single white space to join and split, I get "" after splitting into several lists. How can I prevent this?

```
[
 ['chain 2109 chrY 59373566 + 1266734 1266761 chrX 156040895 + 1198245 1198272 20769290','27',''],
 ['','chain 2032 chrY 59373566 + 1136192 1136219 chrX 156040895 + 1086629 1086656 4047064','27','']
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend splitting your list with [`more_itertools.split_at`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_at).

Because your original list ends with the separator, `'\n'`, splitting it will result in the final item of your list being an empty sublist. The `if` check excludes this.

```
from more_itertools import split_at

original = [
    'chain 2109 chrY 59373566 + 1266734 1266761 chrX 156040895 + 1198245 1198272 20769290\n',
    '27\n',
    '\n',
    'chain 2032 chrY 59373566 + 1136192 1136219 chrX 156040895 + 1086629 1086656 4047064\n',
    '27\n',
    '\n'
]

processed = [
    [item.rstrip() for item in sublist]
    for sublist in split_at(original, lambda i: i == '\n')
    if sublist
]

print(processed)
```

Output (line break added for clarity):

```
[['chain 2109 chrY 59373566 + 1266734 1266761 chrX 156040895 + 1198245 1198272 20769290', '27'],
 ['chain 2032 chrY 59373566 + 1136192 1136219 chrX 156040895 + 1086629 1086656 4047064', '27']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for you?

```
list1 = ['chain 2109 chrY 59373566 + 1266734 1266761 chrX 156040895 + 1198245 1198272 20769290\n', '27\n','\n','chain 2032 chrY 59373566 + 1136192 1136219 chrX 156040895 + 1086629 1086656 4047064\n','27\n','\n']

list2 = []
tmp = []
for item in list1:
    if item != '\n':
        tmp.append(item.rstrip('\n'))
    else:
        #Note we aren't actually processing this item of the input list, as '\n' by itself is unwanted
        list2.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension to strip the `\n` item from the list and use `.strip()` to remove the `\n` at the end of the lines you want to keep. Then loop through the temp list (`blist`) and create your final list.

```
alist = ['chain 2109 chrY 59373566 + 1266734 1266761 chrX 156040895 + 1198245 1198272 20769290\n', '27\n','\n','chain 2032 chrY 59373566 + 1136192 1136219 chrX 156040895 + 1086629 1086656 4047064\n','27\n','\n']

# use line comprehension to remove the \n from the list
# and use the .strip() to remove the trailing \n in the strings
blist = [i.strip() for i in alist if i != '\n']

final_list = []
for i in range(0,len(blist),2):
    final_list.append( [blist[i], blist[i+1]] )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

seq = ['chain 2109 chrY 59373566 + 1266734 1266761 chrX 156040895 + 1198245 1198272 20769290\n', '27\n','\n','chain 2032 chrY 59373566 + 1136192 1136219 chrX 156040895 + 1086629 1086656 4047064\n','27\n','\n']

result = [
    [string.rstrip() for string in group]
    for key, group in groupby(seq, lambda s: s != "\n")
    if key
]
```

Result:

```
[
    ['chain 2109 chrY 59373566 + 1266734 1266761 chrX 156040895 + 1198245 1198272 20769290', '27'],
    ['chain 2032 chrY 59373566 + 1136192 1136219 chrX 156040895 + 1086629 1086656 4047064', '27']
]
```